# Undefined method each with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, nested-resources

I'm trying to follow Ryan Bates Polymorphic association tutorial in order to put some comments to my site.

The thing is I have nested resources:

```
  #Nesting Resources
  resources :users do
    resources :photos do
      resources :comments
      resources :tags
    end
  end
```

So I'm getting an error in my view (photos/show)

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I suppose the problem is in my controller, with comments, that is not defined correctly, but since I have nested resources, I don't know how to do it.

#### Photos Controller

```
def show
    @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user = @photo.user
    @commentable = @photo
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
end
```

#### New Comment Partial

```
  <h2>Comments</h2>

<% if @comments.any? %>
    <%= render "comments/comments" %>
<% else %>
    Todavía no hay comentarios
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render "comments/form" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Form partial (comments/form)

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 8 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### Comments partial (comments/comments)

```
<div id="comments">
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment">
      <%= simple_format comment.content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`. As you can guess **you are calling each on a nil object**. Here your `@comments` is nil and hence giving your trouble.

In your view try something like this:

```
<div id="comments">
  <% if @comments %>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <div class="comment">
        <%= simple_format comment.content %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Edit:

*So if you look at your code you have **@comments** till here*:

```
<% if @comments.any? %>
  <%= render "comments/comments" %>
<% else %>
  #do stuff
<% end %>
```

*it's after you call your partial that your @comment is lost* so try this:

```
<% if @comments.any? %>
  <%= render "comments/comments", comments: @comment %>
<% else %>
  #do stuff
<% end %>
```

and then in your view use

```
<div id="comments">
  <% comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment">
      <%= simple_format comment.content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for responding. It wont work...It keeps saying <%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>... Do I need to pass into the form params user_id somewhere? Since I'm dealing with nested resources

Comment: @Gibson yeah you need to pass user id in a hidden field or use it in controller method and by the way that's a problem in form and not your view :)

Comment: but the problem is the same... I'm still getting nil on objects and don't know why...

Comment: can you paste your full view file?

Comment: It's not working... Comments are being lost in new_comment partial so that means Comments are nil in Photo Controller, thats where the problem comes from...But I don't know how to deal with it!